# How to create a java program to let a user login using passcode and store data

Tags: java, user-interface, authentication

I am trying to make a simple java password manager (I'm not worried about how im storing passwords right now as im just trying to get the overall structure correct first). I'm stuck on how I should allow users to login. I have a file where i store usernames and passwords - so, I first use a scanner to get input from the unauthenticated user and check this against the text file to see if this matches with an account. If the user input does match with a username and password how can i then let that user access his User object? The problem i am havin is that this user object has already been created (when the account was made) but how can I then let a user login and get access to all the methods within the user class i.e. changeUserPassword or getPassword?

I have looked at using different design patterns such as observer but I dont think that these are appropriate for what im trying to do.

I am wondering if anyone knows of a design pattern that I can follow or knows an imlplementation that can let me access an object (user) outside of the user class that has already been created (i.e account has already been made) and make changes to it.

```
public void login() throws IOException {
    // use a scanner to get login details
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("email: ");
    String email = s.next();

    System.out.print("password: ");
    String password = s.next();

    String check = email + ", " + password;

    // loop through file and check if we find a matching email and password
    File f = new File("member.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        if (sc.nextLine().equals(check)) {
            System.out.println("Logging in...");
            // how do i now access the user object that matches the username and password that were given?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do if he entered the right email and password, you said you wanted to access an object 'user' but what that user? is it a class or ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't how you would interact with the database. Write a User class that stores user names and passwords. Then write a Database class that reads the text file and creates an ArrayList of User objects. Then Search using User.name, and check User.password to verify before login.

The database will "load" the data from a text file into the ArrayList, which will be what your program will interact with. If you wish to rewrite the text file, write a save function that clears and prints to the relevant file.

Here's an example (from one of my old projects) of a database class that reads students' data in the format:
`name:HARSH|PID:12|major:null|minor:null|CGPA:4.100000|college:null|email:abcd@gmail.com`

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Database{
    public List<Student> studentList;
    private long lastModified;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    public Object loadDb()
    {//Loads the database from file.
        File data = new File("database.db");
        if(lastModified == data.lastModified())
        {
            return studentList;//Returning main memory;
        }
        Scanner sc;
        try
        {
            sc = new Scanner(data).useDelimiter("\n");//To get individual lines.
            String line;
            if(studentList!=null)
            {//Clearing main memory.
                studentList.clear();
            }
            else
            {//Creating new main memory.
                studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
            }

            while(sc.hasNext())
            {
                line = sc.next();
                Scanner l = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("\\|");//To get info
                String name, PID, major, minor, cgpaSt, college, email;
                name = l.next().split(":")[1];
                PID = l.next().split(":")[1];
                major = l.next().split(":")[1];
                minor = l.next().split(":")[1];
                cgpaSt = l.next().split(":")[1];
                college = l.next().split(":")[1];
                email = l.next().split(":")[1];
                double CGPA = Double.valueOf(cgpaSt);
                Student stud = new Student(name,PID, major, minor, CGPA, college, email);//Creating new student with same info.
                studentList.add(stud);//Adding the student to memory.
            }
            sc.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        return studentList;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void updateDb(Object studList)
    {//Updates the database.
        File data = new File("database.db");
        PrintWriter fs;
        try
        {
            fs = new PrintWriter(data);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("IO Exception!");
            return;
        }
        fs.flush();
        ArrayList<Student>studs = (ArrayList<Student>)studList;
        for(int i = 0;i<studs.size();i++)
        {
            fs.print(studs.get(i).toString());
            if(i != studs.size() -1)
            {
                fs.print("\n");
            }
        }
        fs.close();
        lastModified = data.lastModified();
        loadDb();//Loading updated database.
    }


}
```

You will have to write a `toString()` function for your user class, and modify the reading as per your format. This will allow you to create a variable `Database userData = new Database();` in your central class. You can then interact with the studentList (userList in your case), and search for that user, then check if their password is correct.